# Why my sql doesn't execute?

Tags: python, oracle

I have a python script that needs to update a database information.
So, in my init() method, I start the connection. But when I call
the update method, the script does not give me any answer, it seems
like it is into an infinite loop.

```
def update(self,id,newDescription):
     try:
         sql="""UPDATE table SET table.new_string=:1 WHERE table.id=:2"""                                                                               
         con=self.connection.cursor()
         con.execute(sql,(newDescription,id))
         con.close()
     except Exception,e:
         self.errors+=[str(e)]
```

What I've tried so far:

- Change the query, just to see if the connection is alright. When I did that (I used 'SELECT info from table'), the script worked.
- I thought that my query was wrong, but when I execute it in SQLDeveloper
  program, it goes right.

What can be happening?

Thanks

Comment: First, have you checked if you get any exceptions?

Answer (score 2):

You are forgetting to call `commit`.

Comment: The script stops in the con.execute line.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about how to do it in python script, but i think you need to call a "commit" before closing connection. Otherwise oracle rollsback your transaction.

Try adding con.commit() before close()